# Method ends when reading TCP socket data

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, tcp, listener

I am trying to capture all data sent via a TCP Port, [based on this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx). However once all of the data has been gathered the statement randomly ends on

```
i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

Once the `while` loop has gathered all the data I need to then use this lower down, not for it to just stop. No errors are thrown either. How should I do this?

```vb
i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
While(i<> 0)
    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
    'On second loop, once all data has been gathered, the program just drops out after this line
    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    MessageBox.Show(data)
End While
```

Comment: Did you try surround it with an exception handler?

Comment: In what sense "statement randomly ends"? Program terminates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [**`NetworkStream.Read()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) will cause it to ***block*** until there is data available for reading, though this behaviour is for some reason not mentioned in the documentation (I believe it was before?). If there is data to read the call will just return immediately.

To avoid this blocking your code once you've read everything you can check if there's data to read via the stream's [**`DataAvailable` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx), which will return `False` if there currently is no data to read:

```vb
While stream.DataAvailable
```

Be advised though that neither this method nor your previous one takes delayed data into account. If the data is for some reason delayed (for instance due to a slow connection) it might not get read by this code unless you run it again.